# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (2,) Curve_fit()

Tags: python, curve-fitting, valueerror

I'm using code in which I have 2 arrays. These arrays are then used to fit a function to the data they contain. I want to try and make a linear fit for all neighbouring points, for example:

```
if
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10, 15, 65, 123, 200]
```

Then I want a fit between 10-15(1-2), 15-65(2-3), 65-123(3-4),...

When I try this with my code:

```
   for i in range(0, len(height)):
      for j in range(0, len(height[i])-1):
         popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc, wavelengths, [height[i][j],height[i][j+1]])
```

With fitfunc:

```
def fitfunc(x, a, b):
   return a*x + b
```

I get the above mentioned error.. Any suggestions or comments?

PS heights has dimension 18x8 and wavelengths is a 1D array with length 8

Comment: What are the shapes of the input arrays?

Comment: You don't need the second loop on "j". Replace [height[i][j],height[i][j+1]] by [height[i],height[i+1]]

Comment: @T.Lucas I edited my question, height is a 2D array

Comment: @MadPhysicist I put it in the question, but height is 18x8 and wavelengths 1D with length 8

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the two loops?

Comment: Well height is 2D and each row of it contains a certain dataset for an altitude. So each row of height represents a number of measurements which belong together and I want to fit a linear function between each two following points of the row but can't seem to read in the data in such a way.. So I want a fit for height[i][j] and height[i][j+1] and then for height[i][j+1] and height[i][j+2],... and this for every row hence the two loops...

Comment: I think I found my error, it's in the fact that I'm trying to fit the two datapoints to the whole array of wavelengths, which has len 8 so that's that.